# how to implement jenkins ci/cd pipeline for node js application which should be run using docker compose

Tags: node.js, jenkins, docker-compose, cicd

I've NodeJS application which I dockerized.
I'm running this application in the server using `docker compose`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3030
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3030:3030'
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
```

Is this possible to implement Jenkins which should update project source code from Github repository and after updating source code (`git pull`) run `docker compose up -d --build` again?

This is the example Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:lts-bullseye-slim'
      args '-p 3000:3000'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    stage ('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh 'cd ~/projects/jenkins-starter-nodejs-app'
        sh 'docker compose down'
        sh 'docker compose up -d --build'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76082369/13567897) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to install and configure specific plugin. Let's assume we're talking about integration with GitHub.

1. Install this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/
2. Enable `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling`
3. Add Jenkins webhook URL and select `push` event type in GutHub repo settings

[Step by step instruction for non-multibranch job](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/github-webhook-non-multibranch-jobs)

Configuration steps depends on the type of Jenkins job https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/github-webhook-configuration

In your example all commands are executed inside container and container is destroyed after pipeline execution. If you want to run your application on server connected as node to Jenkins, you can rebuild the images via the docker compose command. It could be something like this (for development purposes):

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label '<node_name>'
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build and Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d'
      }
    }
  }
}
```